# Odoo `field_description` is Assigned But Not Applied

Tags: python, odoo

I'm successfully creating an Odoo module and now i'm about to get it a finishing touch.

So in my .py files i have a field that named `x_show_in_ecommerce` and `x_description_sale_ecommerce`. I've assigned it's `field_description`, but in Odoo it doesn't seems to be applied.

I expect this `Field Label` to be filled with other words as i already assigned in my .py files, but what i get is the same name as the field itself but without space.

[image]

This also affect the fields list available when exporting into excel

[image]

Here's my .py files :

```
class ProductTemplateInherited(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    x_show_in_ecommerce = fields.Boolean(field_description="Show In Ecommerce", store=True, help="If this checkbox filled, this product will show in Central E-Commerce", ttype="boolean")
    x_description_sale_ecommerce = fields.Text(field_description="Description Sale Ecommerce", store=True, help="A description of the Product that you want to communicate to your customers. This description will be pulled to E-Commerce", ttype="text")
```

Thank you for your help and insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `string` instead of `field_description`:

```
x_show_in_ecommerce = fields.Boolean(string="Show In Ecommerce", store=True, help="If this checkbox filled, this product will show in Central E-Commerce", ttype="boolean")
x_description_sale_ecommerce = fields.Text(string="Description Sale Ecommerce", store=True, help="A description of the Product that you want to communicate to your customers. This description will be pulled to E-Commerce", ttype="text")
```

Comment: Working great! thank you for your help! Do you have any idea why it `string` and not `field_description`? is it a bug?

Comment: @altela Sorry, I have no idea about that. I just have been using `string` and never used `field_description`.

Comment: Defining fields in code is using the `Field` class (and its inheriting classes) where `field_description` is not used in the `__init__` (constructor). Just take a look into the doc or better into the code (odoo/fields.py) to find out which parameters are used/possible. What you refer to is the model `ir.model.fields` which is sort of a method of persisting the field into the database. I don't know why odoo was mixing or changing names between those two, but i never looked into it either.